# C++11 : left operand of comma operator has no effect

Tags: c++11, null

I'm getting this warning after I started using C++11 on my project

This is the piece of code that gives the warning :

```
    std::string errortext = "cannot find suitable conversion for %d", index;
    LogToFile(NULL, errortext);
    Assert(false && "cannot find suitable conversion");
    return NULL;
```

If I remove the NULL, will the piece of code still do the same thing ?
Or is there any way to fix it ?

```
#ifndef Assert
    #include <assert.h>
    #define Assert assert
    #define LogToFile (void)(0);
#endif
```

Comment: What is `LogToFile`?

Comment: @Yu Hao It is defind in Assert to write the errors into a file
     #ifndef Assert
        #include <assert.h>
    #define Assert assert
    #define LogToFile (void)(0);
#endif

Comment: Please edit the definition of `LogToFile` into the question, so that we can see it with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogToFile` is defined as an "object-like" macro (one that takes no arguments), not as a function-like macro.

Given the definition:

```
#define LogToFile (void)(0);
```

this line:

```
LogToFile(NULL, errortext);
```

expands to this:

```
(void)(0); (NULL, errortext);
```

That's two separate statements. The second is an expression statement, where the expression is a parenthesized comma expression (the comma is a comma operator, not an argument separator). The left operand of the comma operator is `NULL`.

Assuming it always takes two arguments, you can change the definition to:

```
#define LogToFile(arg1, arg2) ((void)(0))
```

If it takes a variable number of arguments, you can define it as a variadic macro:

```
#define LogToFile(...) ((void)(0))
```

(Note: I've added extra parentheses to the definition.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of the time, `LogToFile` is defined as a macro with arguments, and other times without:

```
#if 0
#define LogToFile(x, y) some_log_function(x, y, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
#else
#define LogToFile (void)(0);
#endif
```

This causes expansion as follows:

```
(void)(0);(NULL, errortext);
```

and the warning you see.

A *much* better option is to use the same number of arguments in both cases:

```
#if 0
#define LogToFile(x,y) some_log_function(x, y, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
#else
#define LogToFile(x,y) (void)(y)
#endif
```

In fact, the original was horribly broken, since it varies from one statement to two, which will not behave as intended if it is the controlled statement of a conditional or loop.